# measurability of argmin

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, optimization, calculus-of-variations, measurable-functions

Define for every $\omega\in\Omega$:
$$f_\omega=\operatorname{argmin}_{f\in S} L(\omega,f)$$

where

- $\Omega$ is a measurable space
- $S\subseteq \big(C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^n),\|{\cdot}\|_\infty\big)$ compact
- $L\colon\, \Omega\times C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^n)\to [0,\infty)$
- $\omega \mapsto L(\omega,f)$ is measurable for every $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^n)$
- $C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^n) \ni f \mapsto L(\omega,f)$ is continuous for every $\omega\in\Omega$

---

Can we choose the minimizer $f_\omega$ for every $\omega$ in a way such that the mapping

$(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^d) \ni(\omega,x)\mapsto f_{\omega}(x)$

is measurable?

---

Idea:
I think that Theorem 18.19 in Aliprantis & Border 2006 could be applicable?
([Measurability of supremum over measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490937/measurability-of-supremum-over-measurable-set?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: Yes, you just have to get a measurable selection from the argmin-correspondence by the Kuratowski--Ryll-Nardzewski selection theorem.