# Measurability of the max function.

Tags: measure-theory, maxima-minima, borel-sets

Could someone help me with the following problem?

Let $S$ be a compact metric space, $\mu$ be a Borel measure on a Souslin space, $f:S\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous in the first argument, and Borel measurable in the second argument. Show that there is a Borel measurable function $F:X\to S$ such that $F(x)$ is a point of maximum of $f(x,s)$ over $s\in S$.

I was given two hints:

1. We are looking for the function $F$ such $f(F(x),x)=\max\limits_{s\in S}f(x,s)$
2. We may use the fact that a Borel measurable mapping between Souslin spaces has a Borel measurable right inverse.

This question might seems as duplicate of the question [Measurability of supremum over measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490937/measurability-of-supremum-over-measurable-set), but the answer looks like an overkill. I'm looking for a more down to Earth solution.

Comment: Do you really mean the function is $F:X\rightarrow S$, instead of $F:S\rightarrow X$?

Comment: @Michael, thank you! This is a typo. Now fixed.

Comment: I wonder if the axiom of choice is needed here, or if you can use the metric to uniquely break ties when there are many $s \in S$ that maximize $f(x,s)$ for a given $x$.  For example you could try to break ties by picking a point $v \in S$ and choosing the maximizer that is closest to $v$, but you are not guaranteed to have a unique closest one.